# How to block all Stream sources completely in SOLR

Tags: solr, streaming

I am working on securing solr and one thing caught my thought is to disable stream sources completely by:-

1. Disable multipart uploads
2. Disable POST requests which are not having `content-type` header
3. Disallow `stream.body` parameter.
4. Keep the remote stream disabled.

I seek an advice is it a wise thing to do the above. If yes then how to disable multipart uploads in solr. After searching through google I did not get enough to get by. Rather thought to do the following

I wish the community to share the thoughts on how to achieve this.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the [regular rule based authentication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html) instead of worrying where the data comes from?

Comment: @MatsLindh We already have a custom plugin that works for us with all features provided by Rule based auth. and some specific use cases that we are handling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way of doing it.
Use the Node based proxy.

https://github.com/dergachev/solr-security-proxy